# Spring @RestController annotation with root context from beans.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm replacing my Jersey Rest Controllers with Spring 4 MVC. So I converted all Controllers to a spring mvc RestController. The problem is that I can't get the controllers to work. This is my Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController { 

    // .... //

    // Spring xml injections
    private PersonService personService;
    public void setPersonService(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }
}
```

The bean is configured with an xml configuration ->
person-beans.xml:

```
<bean id="personController" class="de.some.package.PersonController">
    <property name="personService" ref="personService"/>
</bean>
```

And the complete application is build together in a file called beans.xml ->
beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <import resource="classpath:spring/person-beans.xml"/>
    <!-- and some more.. -->

</beans>
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/spring/beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

I think I need to add:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="de.some.package" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

In order to have that @RestController annotation working but then the injections into my PersonController class is null (so here the personService).

Is there a way to use the spring configuration from the beans.xml together with the @RestController annotation?

Comment: As you said, if you add `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, you will be able to have both annotations and Spring xml config files.

Comment: Where should this <mvc:annotation-driven /> be placed?

Comment: From what you showed us, in your `beans.xml` file that seems to be the beginning of your Spring config.

Comment: Ok that seems to work somehow. I guess my problem was that I used component-scan and annotation-driven together before. If you want you can answer the question and I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, if you add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your `beans.xml` file, you will be able to have both annotations and Spring xml config files